# Automatically running PHPUnit tests with Arcanist (Phabricator)

Tags: phpunit, phabricator, arcanist

A "simple" question: how can I automatically run PHPunit tests with Arcanist?

According to the [documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/unit_tests/) I should first load a custom library. As stated [here](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_lint_unit/) I should create a `.arcconfig` file and load the appropriate library.

So: I've create a dir "arc_libs" in my project and in the dir "src" I used `arc liberate` to generate the needed files. My config is now:

```
{
  "project.name" : "arc_libs",
  "phabricator.uri" : "https://phabricator.xxx.xxx.net/",
  "unit.engine" : "PhpunitTestEngine",
  "load" : ["arc_libs/src"]
}
```

The libary DOES get loaded because I can run `arc unit`

```
[matthijs@xx xxx]$ arc unit
No tests to run.
```

But as you can see there are no tests to run. We keep our tests in "project_root/tests" and as far as I understand the [documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/unit_tests/) I should create a __tests__ dir in "the module" (probably my arc_libs dir ?)

However I want to run my existing PHPunit test files, not new tests I need to create. I tried using a symlink etc but I cannot get it to work. Arcanist doesn't detect my tests.

So my question: How can I automatically run my EXISTING PHPunit tests with arcanist?

(note we use `arc diff` that should run `arc unit` automatically)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked won't be very useful - it's aimed at Phabricator developers who want to test their libraries. [There is some user-facing documentation for customising unit test tasks](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_lint_unit/), but it's not great. Fortunately, it's quite easy to get Arcanist to run your project's unit tests using the included `PhpunitTestEngine`:

1. Prepare a `phpunit.xml` file in your project root. This should be [a standard PHPUnit configuration file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html). You can test this by running `phpunit -c phpunit.xml`.
2. Add a `phpunit_config` option to your `.arcconfig`:

   ```
   {
     "phabricator.uri": "https://phabricator.xxx.xxx.net/",
     "unit.engine": "PhpunitTestEngine",
     "phpunit_config": "phpunit.xml"
   }
   ```
3. Run `arc unit` to test it out.

Although user documentation is thin on the ground, [the source code for `PhpunitTestEngine`](https://secure.phabricator.com/diffusion/ARC/browse/master/src/unit/engine/PhpunitTestEngine.php) has some comments and is fairly concise. If you run into problems, reading through the test engine code can help you track it down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We already use a separate phpunit.xml I changed the config to what you indicate but unfortunately arc still thinks there are no tests to run. I'd be happy to post our phpunit xml file but I don't think that is relevant, just running phpunit works like a charm. I'll look into the source code and see if there is anything that I can use.

Comment: Still no luck with this option, if anyone else can recommend something it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ arc unit --help

  unit [options] [paths]
  unit [options] --rev [rev]
      Supports: git, svn, hg
      Run unit tests that cover specified paths. If no paths are specified,
      unit tests covering all modified files will be run.
```

By default, arc lint and arc unit are meant to be used as part of a process of making changes, so by default it only acts on changed files. Odds are, you don't have any changed files. You probably want to specify some paths, or run `arc unit --everything` to run all tests.